# Generate near table failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have been generating near tables for the nearest neighbour, for weeks now with the same files, but when I tried it today it would not work. Here is a snapshot of the error. I also have one input feature, and one near feature.

How do I fix this?

The only thing I have done differently on my laptop is change the folders around, but I have exported the data to Arcmap from these new folders.

I have also double checked and the attribute tables are not empty. Everything looks the way it should.

[image]

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the full error message as *text*. You should also include the result of your research into the 001143 error code, and what steps you have taken in response. An example of what you mean by "change the folders around" would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to occur with a variety of processes and tools, usually involving larger datasets, from what I have seen on some esri forum threads. the help file for the error suggests turning off background processing, as this is where the problem occurs (http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000024001143).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it does work if I turn off the background process